# In AsyncSocket framework, how to do more than one Socket Connection in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sockets, asyncsocket, cocoaasyncsocket

I am now using AsyncSocket for iPhone socketing connection development.
http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/

But I am having problem that, how to connect 2 multi-server to collect data from server?

I have host IP address A: 201.22.33.XXX.XX
   and host IP address B: 202.33.XXX.XX

I can success connect one server  to collect data. 
But how to collect both server at the same time?

I tried create two socket objects with their own delegates, my path is like that:
step 1 ---- Connect to A
step 2 ----  Connect to B
Step 3 ----  Disconnect B
but at this moment when i disconnect B, A also disconnected....

Please help.

Comment: Host IP address A is invalid, so that might be your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create two socket objects with their own delegates.  I have several applications that connect to multiple servers at once.

Comment: can you give me more information about two socket objects with their own delegates?

Comment: I tried create two socket objects with their own delegates, my path is like that:   
step 1 ====  Connect to A
step 2 ====  Connect to B
Step 3 ====  Disconnect B
but at this moment when i disconnect B, A also disconnected....

please help >.<a

Comment: I am still have trouble with this issue, would u mind make a simple example to explain?thx !!

Comment: I am still having problem with this question,please help >.<

Comment: It sounds as if the delegates for A and B could be referencing the same object. Did you accidentally set the delegate for both AsyncSocket A and B objects to the same object (such as `self`?) You might want something like this (example only; I have never used AsyncSocket): `AsyncSocket *soA = [[AsyncSocket alloc] init]; [soA setDelegate:delegateObjectA]; AsyncSocket *soB = [[AsyncSocket alloc] init]; [soB setDelegate:delegateObjectB];`

Comment: @nullmicgo If your problem is solved,please explain and accept the answer.

Comment: I did not found out the answer yet...
For now,i opened two different AsyncSocketDelegate,
for example, if you want to have two socket connection together,
my method is 

FirstAsyncSocketDelegate.h FirstAsyncSocketDelegate.m

SecondAsyncSocketDelegate.h SecondAsyncSocketDelegate.m


But this method still having trouble sometimes...such as close one connection , and another also closed sometimes..